# Evaluating kartik-Widget DateTimepicker in yii2

Tags: yii2

I succesfully implementated kartik-Widget 'DateTimepicker' using following code

```html
use kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker;
.
.
.
.
<?php
echo '<label>Start Date/Time</label>';
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'dp_2',
    'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
    'value' => '01-Jan-2017 10:00',
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii']]);
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'zahl_down')->textInput(['value' => $zahl_down])->hint('Die kleinste Zahl,bitte')->label('Zahl(Minimum)') ?> 
.
.
.
.
```

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to evaluate users choice, 'cause there is no relation to a model. For instance, I evaluate zahl_down like this:

```
<li><label>Startwert:</label> <?= Html::encode($model->zahl_down) ?><label>...bis...</label></li>
```

Any ideas how to evaluate DateTimePicker?

Comment: you need $model->zahl_down's value to be as selected from the datetime picker ?

Comment: No! Just an example how to evaluate zahl_down,which actually refers to model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not able to get your issue .. but still i guess you want to relate model to the widget consider this in that case

```
<?php
echo '<label>Start Date/Time</label>';
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute'=>'attribute_name',
    'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
    'value' => '01-Jan-2017 10:00',
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'autoclose'=>true,
    'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii']]);
?>
```

or

```
echo $form->field($model, 'attribute_name')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), [
    'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii'
    ]
]);
```

Define "attribute_name" in model

Answer (score 1):

According to your model:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'datepicker')->widget(DateTimePicker::classname(), [
'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
'pluginOptions' => [
'autoclose'=>true,
'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii']]
]);
```

For more examples you can check out the [offical guide](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datetimepicker)

**Update:**

You need to define your model attribute inside your model first. This can be done by adding the attribute.

```
public $datepicker;

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'datepicker' => 'Date Picker',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Your answer is nonsense. I want to evaluate users' choice, not printing out widget, again!

Comment: Have you defined an active form?  Like this: $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?

Comment: Of Course, I did. 'cause there is no relation from DateTimePicker to a model, i can't evaluate. That's the Problem!

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue. You need to define your DateTimePicker Attribute inside your model first. It is described here [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#defining-attributes)

Comment: zahl_down just is an example!! DateTimepicke has no relation to a model,'cause it's generated by echo